# Comparing strings in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am using a LINQ Query, which is not working some times.
Few times it work, but few times i do not get my answer.

The query is

```
int a=0;

if (!Projects.Any(p => p.ID.Equals(PID)))
{
    a = 0;
}
else
{
    a= 10;
}
```

Here, Projects is an Enumerable of a class where it contains ID. So, even if there is an item which is same as PID, it wont come inside the ELSE loop.
I debugged it and saw that there is 10 count of Projects and 1 item is having an ID same as PID, but still its not coming in the ELSE loop.

PID and ID are Strings.

Why is this not working ?

I even tried :

```
 if (!Projects.Any(p => p.ID==PID))
```

**Updated:**

I want to go in the Else loop.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do here, do you want a to be equal to 10 afterwards if there isn't a project with the given ID?

Comment: Look at the memory of both strings in the debugger. You will likely find that one of them has unexpected trailing spaces or some other unexpected characters.

Comment: @GrantWinney I updated. I want it to go in the else loop.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you don't want:

```
if (Projects.Any(p => p.ID.Equals(PID)))
```

The way you have it currently, it will *only* go inside the block if *none* of the IDs is equal to `PID`.

If you are actually trying to get it to go into the `else` block, then I would suggest taking into consideration what Eric Lippert said and trim off any whitespace that might be there:

```
PID = PID.Trim();
if (!Projects.Any(p => p.ID != null && p.ID.Trim().Equals(PID)))
```

And if that still doesn't work, inspect the values in the debugger for any anomalies that the values might have.